# Subsetting a vector using another boolean vector in R

Tags: r, subset, iterable-unpacking

Using the following two R vectors, I want to extract a subset of `valMe` using the boolean values in `boolMe`. In addition, I would like to have two possible outputs, one where the FALSE values in `boolMe` are ommited from `valMe`, and one where the FALSE values are replaced by NA. Further illustration of what I want to do in code:

**Input**

```
boolMe<-c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
valMe<-1:6
```

**Intended output**

```
NA 2 3 4 NA 6
```

or

```
2 3 4 6
```

Comment: In python, I would do it something like this: `>>> a=[False, True, False, False, False, False]
>>> b=[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> [bb for (aa,bb) in zip(a,b) if aa]
[11]`

Comment: In `python3`, `import itertools; list(itertools.compress(b ,a))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can directly index `valMe` by using the `[` operator:

```
> valMe[boolMe]
[1] 2 3 4 6
```

See section [2.7 of the intro manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors) for more detail.

Comment: How would you do it if you have a matrix instead and you want to keep all columns?

Answer (score 8):

Similarly, if you want the NAs:

```
> valMe[!boolMe] <- NA
> valMe
[1] NA  2  3  4 NA  6
```

The `!` negates the logical boolean so you select the values you want missing.  Then, in a touch of R awesomeness, you assign NA to the selected values.